# C, free() and pointers arithmetic

Tags: c, free, pointer-arithmetic

```
int *p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
free(p+n/2);
```

In the code shown above will the free function deallocate the whole last half of the array or only the p+n/2 "cell"?

Comment: it won't dealloc anything, you must pass it the a pointer you originally malloced

Comment: No. You can only deallocate the whole block (by passing the pointer to the begining of the block)

Comment: Generic warning: Do not cast the result of `malloc()`!

Answer (score 3):

It's not legal to pass an expression like (p+n/2) to `free()`. You can only pass a pointer returned from one of the `malloc()` functions to `free()`. So you have to free the whole array at once.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer value passed to `free` must be either a null pointer or a pointer to previously allocated memory. Otherwise the behavior is undefined (which means your program might crash, or you might corrupt internal runtime data structures, or, worst of all, it might behave as you expect).

Quoting the C11 standard (draft [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.22.3.3p2):

> The **`free`** function causes the space pointed to by **`ptr`** to be
>   deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If **`ptr`** is
>   a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if the argument does not
>   match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or
>   if the space has been deallocated by a call to **`free`** or **`realloc`**, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Comment: Worst of all, it might behave as you expect, until a customer uses your application, and then all hell breaks loose :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, no.

`free()` gives undefined behaviour if it is given a pointer that was not returned by `malloc()` (a NULL pointer is the only exception, but causes `free()` to have no effect).

Your example is passing a pointer that was not returned by `malloc()` - albeit it is calculated from that pointer.

The result of your sample is undefined behaviour.

If you want to allocate memory and later change the allocated size, look up `realloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code shown above will the free function deallocate the whole last half of the array or only the p+n/2 "cell"?

No, while deallocating it will give a undefined behavior. Since `malloc` returns the starting address of the memory location, you can use that pointer as reference to access all the memory locations allocated.

You can only free the pointer allocated by the `malloc`, if you try to free from in-between as per your logic inside free function it will give an error of invalid pointer.

> free(): invalid pointer:

or you can use `realloc` as suggested in others, which is best if you want to modify the size of the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You must only pass a pointer returned from `malloc/calloc/realloc` to `free`

There is a special practical reason [aside from whatever the standards say] for this.  `free` *needs to know the byte length of the allocated area.*  Likewise, `realloc` needs to know the byte length of *currently* allocated area.

At the front of any such allocated area, there is a *hidden* header struct that describes the area to the various heap functions.  For example:

```
struct memory_descriptor {
    u32 magic;                          // magic number
    size_t length;                      // memory area length in bytes
    struct memory_descriptor *next;     // next memory area
    struct memory_descriptor *prev;     // previous memory area
};
```

The layout of a memory chunk actually looks like this:

```
| memory_descriptor | usable memory area ... |
                      ^
                      |
                      + pointer returned by malloc et. al.
```

When you `free` something, it takes the pointer and subtracts the descriptor size to locate the descriptor struct and uses that to determine the memory area size.

If you passed something like `pointer + 10`, `free` wouldn't find the descriptor.  It would use whatever is there.  That's why, in this example, there is a "magic number field" to try to detect this misuse.

Comment: Well, on MacOS X for example and probably other implementations there is usually no such header in sight for small allocations. And no "next" and "prev" for any allocations.

Comment: @gnasher729 Just an example.  I've written a few heap allocs from scratch.  The pointers can be useful for integrity checking.  If you enable it [dynamically], you can bidirectionally check list and get better corruption info.  Without debug, a size is possibly sufficient [with magic].  On small alloc, it comes from subpool [detectable by address range] which is [say] page aligned.  You round down to find a bitmap. Or "power of 2" subpool schemes with "out-of-band" headers. But, they usually require a list scan to find subpool header that describes the fixed size alloc block